# Trying to run lein repl and could not transfer artifact org.clojure:tools.nrepl:pom:0.2.3 from/to central

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I have installed leiningen in windows xp with `lein.bat` and running `lein self-install`. 
I have configured the environment variables

```
LEIN_JAR=C:\.lein\bin\leiningen-2.3.4-standalone.jar
LEIN_JAVA_CMD=C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe
PATH={...blah blah blah}; C:\.lein\bin ;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

But when I try to run a `REPL`, I get this:

```
lein repl

Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:tools.nrepl:pom:0.2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): repo1.maven.org
Could not transfer artifact clojure-complete:clojure-complete:pom:0.2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): repo1.maven.org
This could be due a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

I am connecting in the company's LAN, and I am not connected in a proxy server, but anyway, I tried configuring the `http_no_proxy` variable.

> http_no_proxy=(to maven repository above, I am new here and i can't
>   post more than 2 links)

Am I missing something? what am I doing wrong?

*PS: I've tried to install it with the leiningen installer for windows, but it didn't work either.*

Answer (score 3):

Solved. The problem was in network permissions. I had to do the same steps in another computer and download all the maven dependencies and then copy them to the server and it worked. I think I could have fixed it too by changing the maven configuration, but I'm not sure how to do it.